# create data.frame for time course

Tags: r, dataframe, vector

I've got some large data files with biometric time course data for different subjects. I've already been able to average subsets of data and export specific one number metrics, and now I am attempting to modify my code to actually save the raw time course data (i.e., subsets of data) into a data.frame for later averaging and visualization.

I have tried setting up a date.frame like this:

```
results = data.frame(filename = character(), SubNum = numeric(), 
APTCode = character(), Pcode = character(), 
FAAdata = logical(), FixPlus_AvgFAA = numeric(), 
FAA_pringles = t(vector(mode = 'numeric', length = 25)), 
FAA_ax = t(vector(mode = 'numeric', length = 25)), 
FAA_pin = t(vector(mode = 'numeric', length = 25)), 
FAA_inf = t(vector(mode = 'numeric', length = 25)), 
FAA_lev = t(vector(mode = 'numeric', length = 25)), 
FAA_col = t(vector(mode = 'numeric', length = 25)))
```

My idea is to have a data frame with several transposed numeric vectors of length 25 that can be set to zero, and then filled in with the appropriate subsets. But R doesn't like this expression, and I get the following error:

```
 Error in data.frame(filename = character(), SubNum = numeric(), APTCode = character(),  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 0, 1
```

I seem to be able to get it to work for 1 vector, but not for more than one vector, i.e., this works:

```
try1 = data.frame(longvector = t(vector(mode = 'numeric', length = 25)))
```

But this doesn't work:

```
try2 = data.frame(longvector = t(vector(mode = 'numeric', length = 25), bigvector2 = t(vector(mode = 'numeric', length = 25))))
```

I get the error:

```
Error in t(vector(mode = "numeric", length = 25), bigvector2 = t(vector(mode = "numeric",  : 
  unused argument (bigvector2 = t(vector(mode = "numeric", length = 25)))
```

Basically, I need a long string of numbers to hold the extracted subset of data.

Comment: I don't think you want to transpose your vectors... vectors are column vectors by default, so transposing a vector and putting it in a data frame will create one row with multiple columns.

Comment: As for the different lengths, `numeric()` has length zero, so creates an empty column (no rows). `FAA_ax = t(vector(mode = 'numeric', length = 25))` tries to create 25 columns with 1 row (all values default to 0). Your data frame can't have both 0 rows and 1 row, hence the error.

Comment: You can always add columns to a data frame later - I would recommend getting the data values you want and then creating the data frame last, rather than trying to initialize a 0 or 1 row data frame to (presumably) add data to one row at a time.

Comment: Hello Gregor, thanks for your response. You are correct that I am initializing a data.frame and then adding one line at a time, or for each participant. I am actually modifying some existing code that I already have working, hence my desire to just do it this way.

Comment: I think you are right: I don't need to transpose.. I've removed that, but still get an error. Basically, I do want a data.frame with character and other types, as well as vectors of length 25, e.g., [0, 0, 0, 0... 0]. These vectors are meant to be used as containers for time course information that I will want to later average across subjects and plot... but I am having trouble creating a data frame that includes vectors.

Comment: You just need the lengths to match. `numeric()`, `character()`, etc., have a length argument that defaults to 0. You seem to want 25 rows, so use `filename = character(25)` or `filename = rep(NA_character_, 25)` instead of `character()`.

Comment: And do it for everything, `numeric(25)` is the same as `vector(mode = 'numeric', length = 25)`. But `numeric(25)` is shorter and clearer.

Comment: Hi all, I think I might have a way to make this work... when I take a look at how the vectors are created, I think I do need to do a transpose... basically, I want to capture a bunch of time course data as a long series of number. I appear to need the transpose to do that (so the numbers are all in one row, and not in multiple rows). However, it looks like I can use the same format to create character columns, so:

Comment: esults3 = data.frame(filename = t(vector("character", length = 1)), FAA_prin = t(vector("numeric", length = 25)), FAA_ax = t(vector("numeric", length = 25)), FAA_pine = t(vector("numeric", length = 25)), FAA_inf = t(vector("numeric", length = 25)), FAA_lev = t(vector("numeric", length = 25)), FAA_col = t(vector("numeric", length = 25)))

Comment: Okay, I think this might be the solution. Thanks for your help Gregor... results = data.frame(filename = character(1), SubNum = numeric(1), APTCode = character(1), Pcode = character(1), FAAdata = logical(1), FixPlus_AvgFAA = numeric(1), FAA_prin = t(numeric(25)), FAA_ax = t(numeric(25)), FAA_pine = t(numeric(25)), FAA_inf = t(numeric(25)), FAA_lev = t(numeric(25)), FAA_col = t(numeric(25)))

Comment: Okay glad to hear it's working. It looks terribly ugly to me with all the transposed vectors. Also [growing objects in a loop (like adding rows to a data frame one at a time, is the 2nd Circle of R Hell](http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf) - it's terribly inefficient.

Comment: Gregor... I am making progress. Thx again for your help. And, I am curious, what would be a better control structure, given that I need to work through a list of 100 participants with separate data files for each one, including missing data files? I do want to learn to be a better R programmer, and right now I feel like I am kludging my way through.

Comment: It's hard to know without seeing some sample data. If the data all fits in memory, then it probably makes sense [to use a list of data frames](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24376207/903061). If each data frame has the same structure then you can combine them into a single data frame with a `participant` column to tell the rows apart, and then use grouped operations with either `data.table` or `dplyr` to do all your calculating at once.